# Prove that Dinic's algorithm with scaling works in $O(nmlog(C))$

Tags: network-flow

(Given a graph $G$ with $|V|=n,|E|=m, max(c(a,b))=C$ and with integer capacities)
Dinic's algorithm with scaling is defined the following way:

1. set $\Delta = C$;
2. run Dinic's algorithm, only allowing augmenting $\geq\Delta$ at a time (at any point, if edge we're looking at in the created DAG is $<\Delta$, delete it).
3. if $\Delta=1$, end, else set $ \Delta = \lfloor \frac{\Delta}{2} \rfloor$ and go to step 2.

just from complexity of original dinic's algorithm, one could conclude that dinic with scaling works in $O(n^2m log(C))$
, but I need a more strict bound.

Could not find any sources proving it, but many sources cite this fact.

Comment: Proving what?  What is your question? Have you tried finding Dinic's original paper setting out this algorithm?

Comment: Have you read the Notes and References in the Wikipedia article on Dinic's algorithm?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm  I think it would help to summarize what you've found.  See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723

Comment: @D.W. there's no scaling in these links. just from complexity of original dinic's algorithm, one could conclude that dinic with scaling works in $O(n^2 m log(C))$, but I need a more strict bound

Comment: Great!  It would be helpful to [edit] the post to explain that context: to explain what are the standard resources, what bound can be obtained from the standard resources, what bound you are trying to prove, and why you think the bound you're trying to prove is true or where you got it from.  Please state explicitly in the question what your question is.